# Deploy WebAPI alongside web site in IIS on port 80

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I believe this might be a troublesome request but I want to give it due diligence because I didn't know how best to respond to the requester.

We have an AngularJS client that is making a call through $resources to RESTful ASP.NET WebApi services deployed to IIS.

When I was demoing the connections, I served the WebApi on port 56730 out of Visual Studio (IIS Express) and my client's service is structured something like this:

```
app.service('repository', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  var repository = $resource(
    'http://localhost:56730/api/Foo/:component',
    {},
    {
      bars: {
        method: 'GET'
        ,isArray: false
        ,url: 'http://localhost:56730/api/Foo/bars'
      }
    }
  );
  return repository;
}]);
```

To cut right to the chase, he was wondering why the WebAPI was not being served on Port 80 seeing as how it is "just serving json data."  I wanted to respond that it's running inside its own process and the http server is running on port 80, but I wanted to respect his request on the off chance that I can deploy an ASP.NET WebApi project side-by-side with a client site on port 80.

I think this essentially boils down to the desire to have the "/api/{controller}/{id}" area of the site handled by WebAPI and have the http://server.com/resource requests handled as static resources.

Can it be done?
If it can, is it worth the trouble?

Comment: Web Api will use whatever port the server it is deployed to is using (as a website, virtual application, self-hosted, etc...). There is no connection between the AppPool and the port by itself. You can even hook Visual Studio to debug through IIS for the demo and have a proper domain.

Comment: ...I realize that I can serve it on port 80. The question is can I serve WebApi on port 80 at the same time I'm serving a separate web site on port 80?  For instance, I know that Skype interferes with processes attempting to run on port 80.

Comment: The conflict would be if they are both on port 80 with the same domain (i.e. you can't have two website that listen to localhost:80). You can setup IIS to have two website (yourapp.local, api.yourapp.local) listening on the same port.

Comment: You can only have one configured site bound to a single protocol and port. You may have multiple *applications* running on that single site, however.

Comment: So in this case, if I deploy both to port 80 but have an alias set up in my iis applicationhost.config file like "http://external.domain" pointed to localhost and have WebApi served on "http://external.domain:80" instead of "http://localhost:80" I should be ok?

Comment: You can add an application to your existing web site, it can have it's own app pool and can be in a completely different directory. You can probably even use 'api' as the app name and change your project to serve off the root like '/Foo/bars', then your complete url would be `/api/Foo/bars`